# Why is my Speckle (Lee Filter) adding noise instead of reducing noise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, imagefilter

I researched the lee filter according to this:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/help/analysis/raster-functions/speckle-function.htm.

I want it to reduce noise, but it is adding instead.

I have this python function to apply the lee filter to an image:

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import variance
def leeFilter(img, size):
  img_mean = uniform_filter(img, (size, size))
  img_sqr_mean = uniform_filter(img**2, (size, size))
  img_variance = img_sqr_mean - img_mean**2
  overall_variance = np.var(img)

  img_weights = img_variance / (img_variance + overall_variance)
  img_output = img_mean + img_weights * (img - img_mean)
  return img_output
```

Then, I'm applying it to my image as such:

```
currImg = cv2.imread(os.path.join(currPath,f'{i}.png'))
# Get red, green and blue channels
red = currImg[:,:,0]
green = currImg[:,:,1]
blue = currImg[:,:,2]
# Apply the filter
red = lee_filter(red,15)
green = lee_filter(green,15)
blue = lee_filter(blue,15)
# merge channels
currImg[:,:,0] = red
currImg[:,:,1] = green
currImg[:,:,2] = blue
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(newPath,f'{i}.png'),currImg)
```

The problem is that using a window size of 15, it looks like it is **adding** and not **lowering** the noise of the images. Below is a comparison with the before and after images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIaG2.jpg)

Comment: Your `overall_variance` is not the noise's variance. You need to estimate the noise level (== variance of the noise), which is not trivial. There are many noise filters out there that don't require knowing the noise level, and therefore tend to be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cris is right about the estimated noise level, but the main issue is arithmetic **overflow** - result of applying the computations to `uint8` elements.

We may convert the input to `float32` before `lee_filter`, and convert the output back to `uint8` after `lee_filter`.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import variance

def lee_filter(img, size):
    img_mean = uniform_filter(img, (size, size))
    img_sqr_mean = uniform_filter(img**2, (size, size))
    img_variance = img_sqr_mean - img_mean**2
    overall_variance = np.var(img)

    img_weights = img_variance / (img_variance + overall_variance)
    img_output = img_mean + img_weights * (img - img_mean)
    return img_output


currImg = cv2.imread('before.png')
# Get red, green and blue channels
red = currImg[:,:,0].astype(np.float32)  # Convert dtype from np.uint8 to np.float32
green = currImg[:,:,1].astype(np.float32)
blue = currImg[:,:,2].astype(np.float32)
# Apply the filter
red = lee_filter(red, 15)
green = lee_filter(green, 15)
blue = lee_filter(blue, 15)
# merge channels
currImg[:,:,0] = red
currImg[:,:,1] = green
currImg[:,:,2] = blue
currImg = currImg.round().clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert from np.float32 to np.uint8 with rounding and clipping
cv2.imwrite('after.png', currImg)
```

---

Before (`before.png`):
[image]

After (`after.png`):
[image]